# Анализ TLS трафика

Tags: tls

Появилась необходимость анализа трафика отправляемого чужим ПО (клиентская часть), оно взаимодействует с RDP сервером, при прохождении авторизации на сервере заметил что пересылаемый трафик весьма специфичен (а именно этапы обмена TLS handshake) т.к. согласно документации после отправки клиентом сообщения Client Hello - сервер должен отправить сертификат (**клиент первый раз подключается**), но этого не происходит, проанализировав трафик я выделил следующие этапы обмена TLS handshake:

1. **Client** - *ClientHello* + непонятная статическая последовательность
2. **Server** - *ServerHello*, *Change Cipher Spec* + рандомная последовательность БЕЗ ServerHelloDone
3. **Client** - *Change Cipher Spec*
4. **Server** - *Alert* (Предупреждение какое-то)
5. **Client** - *Application Data* (Авторизационные данные)

В основном меня интересуют первые 3 этапа, места которые не удалось расшифровать на картинках я выделил красным, а так же привел в текстовом виде под картинками

**Этап 1: Client Hello + непонятная последовательность**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
00 2d 00 0a 00 06 00 04 00 17 00 18 00 0b 00 02 
01 00 00 0d 00 10 00 0e 04 01 05 01 02 01 04 03 
05 03 02 03 02 02 00 17 00 00 ff 01 00 01 00
```

**Этап 2: ServerHello, Change Cipher Spec + рандомная последовательность**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
7b 7d b4 e6 51 a4 1b 0f 59 f6 8c 8d 92 5e d0 a8 
7a 44 64 bf 90 94 0e 83 a1 71 43 c2 32 84 e3 e4 
4d a3 e4 92 02 91 dd a1 1e e9 42 f1 ad 2c 12 20
```

**Этап 3: Client Change Cipher Spec**

```
14 03 01 00 01 01 16 03 01 00 30 a9 c3 24 d9 9e 
be 48 88 0d 55 24 64 db 9a 74 bd 19 e5 ff 33 f4 
6f 60 38 32 94 90 f0 e8 53 a1 75 eb 1e 96 76 da 
55 cc 94 c0 17 75 e8 b4 fa 1a a4
```

У официального RDP клиента авторизация проходит согласно TLS документации, но у данного клиента (стороннее ПО) почему то процесс авторизации отличается. Прошу Помочь в расшифровке трафика до конца. А так же подскажите пожалуйста какие из этих данных участвуют при шифровании трафика и как они называются (напр. pre-master-secret и т.д.), не получается найти толковых ответов с примерами. Спасибо

Comment: А Wireshark что говорит на это?

Comment: Видит как протокол TPKT и содержимое пакета разбить на части не может, весь hex был скопирован из его поля "Continuation data"

Answer (score 3):

Это не случайные байты, это стандартные расширения TLS.

ClientHello:

```
00 2d - длина блока расширений в байтах

00 0a - тип расширения TLS, в данном случае Supported Groups
00 06 - длина данных расширения
00 04 00 17 00 18 - кривые sect193r1, secp256r1, secp384r1

00 0b - тип расширения, EC Points Format
00 02 - длина данных
01 00 - Uncompressed, ANSIX962CompressedPrime

00 0d - SignatureAlgorithms
00 10 - длина
00 0e 04 01 05 01 02 01 04 03 05 03 02 03 02 02 - разниые комбинации подписей и хешей

00 17 - ExtendedMasterSecret
00 00 - длина

ff 01 - RenegotiationInfo
00 01 - длина
00 - данные
```

ServerHello:

```
00 09 - длина блока расширений

00 17 - ExtendedMasterSecret
00 00 - длина 

ff 01 - RenegotiationInfo
00 01 - длина
00 - данные
```

После ChangeCipherSpec все данные зашифрованы.